# Flutter package pub get encounters "Invoked Dart programs must have a 'main' function defined" error

Tags: flutter, dart

I encountered an issue when executing `flutter pub get` on my Flutter package. The terminal displays an error: "Invoked Dart programs must have a 'main' function defined." This issue arises after upgrading to Flutter 3.10.0 and Dart 3.0.0.

Consequently, [the score on my package's pub.dev site](https://pub.dev/packages/tencent_cloud_chat_uikit/score) is relatively low because it fails to pass the "Dart 3 & Flutter 3.10 compatibility" check.

**image of the compatibility check results** [image: image of the compatibility check results]

However, my package is a Flutter package where a `main` function is not required nor necessary.

I've tried manually adding a `main` function to resolve the issue, but it still didn't work:

**image of the modified code** [image: image of the modified code]

The `pubspec.yaml` of my Flutter package includes the dependencies of flutter.

**image of the `pubspec.yaml`**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOF2G.png)

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file to `main.dart`? Also, have you tried to remove `.pubcache` directory and tried to build it again?

Comment: This problem seems to occur because your package has an errant 0-byte file named `pub` in the project root.  Removing that file should allow `flutter pub get` to make progress.